# Login page password display in the server logs

Tags: html, http, post, authentication

I have an HTML form

```
<form method="post" action="URL">
<input type ="text" name="u">
<input type="password" name = "pass"></form>
```

When I do a form submit, all works fine, but I can see the password in the server logs.Question how does one block the password seen on the logs

Comment: By not logging the password.  Where/how/why are you logging it?

Comment: this wouldn't make the pw show up in logs. either something YOU'RE doing is causing this, or something is rewriting/redirecting the form into a GET query.

Comment: logging is done automatically by the webserver weblogic, thats the reason for he problem

Comment: I am opening a window from the web page & making a call to an external server which requires login

Answer (score 1):

I found that the password is being logged in central, corrected it